Can I Perform a Micro Synthetic Control Analysis with Different Aggregation Levels for Treatment and Control Groups?
I am conducting an analysis using the microsynth package in R to evaluate the impact of increased police presence on various outcome measures obtained from an official survey. My treatment areas consist of specific neighborhoods that have been oversampled for both the baseline and post-intervention surveys. However, the pre-intervention surveys in both the treatment neighborhoods and control neighborhoods have a small number of observations per iteration, leading to imprecise estimates of the outcome variables. To address this, I am considering aggregating the control data at a higher level (district level), while maintaining the treatment data at the neighborhood level.
Given this context, I have a few questions:

Is it methodologically sound to use different levels of aggregation for treatment and control areas in a micro synthetic control analysis? Specifically, I'm concerned that aggregating control areas at the district level while keeping treatment areas at the neighborhood level might introduce biases or invalidate the assumptions underlying the synthetic control method.
The manual for microsynth mentions (under Discussion heading) that the method is an extension of the Synth package, which cautions against aggregating data in the treatment region while leaving control areas disaggregated. Does this imply that aggregating at different levels for treatment and control areas is generally discouraged?
If it is acceptable to proceed with different aggregation levels, are there any specific adjustments or considerations I should take into account when implementing the analysis using microsynth?

I appreciate any insights or references that could help determine whether this approach is valid or if there are better alternatives.

I wonder if the reason you are not getting responses is due to limited number of people who know much about microsynthetic control models? It might help to say a little bit about how they are similar and different to other panel data type models.

You are probably right. I think for this particular question MSC is fairly similar to (normal) synthetic control and even standard difference-in-difference approaches. So any expertise in these methods might translate.
